# ResourceManager problem with MVC localization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, localization, globalization

There is many solutions for localization.
I've decided for this one:
http://geekswithblogs.net/brians/archive/2010/06/14/asp.net-mvc-localization-displaynameattribute-alternatives-a-better-way.aspx

```
public class LocalizedDataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
        {
            protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(
                IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes,
                Type containerType,
                Func<object> modelAccessor,
                Type modelType,
                string propertyName)
            {
                var meta = base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
                    return meta;
                if (meta.DisplayName != null)
                    GetLocalizedDisplayName(meta, propertyName);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(meta.DisplayName))
                    meta.DisplayName = string.Format("[[{0}]]", propertyName);
                return meta;
            }
            private static void GetLocalizedDisplayName(ModelMetadata meta, string propertyName)
            {
                ResourceManager resourceManager = App_GlobalResources.Strings.ResourceManager;
                CultureInfo culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
                meta.DisplayName = resourceManager.GetString(propertyName, culture);
            }
        }
```

I've changed line:

```
if (meta.DisplayName == null)
```

into:

```
if (meta.DisplayName != null)
```

to enter GetLocalizedDisplayName function

In App_GlobalResources there are 2 files:
**Strings.resx** and **Strings.pl.resx**. 
Both of them ahave **Public** access modifier and build action is set to **Embedded Resource**

Whole site is translated but i have problem with **Attributes**

```
[Required]
[LocalizedDisplayName("UserName", NameResourceType = typeof(App_GlobalResources.Strings))]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

I think the problem is in this line from the link that i posted above:

```
meta.DisplayName = resourceManager.GetString(propertyName, culture);
```

GetString always return default value from **Strings.resx**.

**culture** is **pl** and **propertyName** is correct **UserName**, so returned value should be from Strings.**pl**.resx, not from Strings.resx.

Please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

try making build action set to Content.

Comment: Then I have error that server couldn't find resources for specific culture or neutral culture

Source file: {MyProject}\App_GlobalResources\Strings.Designer.cs    Line: 365 

Line 363:        public static string UserName {
Line 364:            get {
Line 365:                return ResourceManager.GetString("UserName", resourceCulture);
Line 366:            }
Line 367:        }